# Im trying to Get a Variable in Smarty/PHP to Assign for a row

Tags: php, mysql, class, smarty

I Have A PHP/MySQL/Smarty Site where dramatically I Have the SQL Table Listed in a HTML Table, I Want to add an extra column for delete / edit. The Data loads perfectly. I can't Seem to get it. Im out of Ideas. Any Help Appreciated.

for my php reference I Extended my own class with smarty.

My PHP:

```
$db_name = $varcor->get("db_name");
$table = $varcor->get("tbl_name");


$varcor->sql->query("SELECT * FROM  `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = '$table' AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = '$db_name'");
$columns = $varcor->sql->resultset();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `$db_name`.`$table`";
$varcor->sql->query($sql);
$result = $varcor->sql->resultset();

$varcor->assign("db", $db_name);
$varcor->assign("table", $table);
```

my smarty/tpl:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="result_table">
        <thead>

            <tr>
                {foreach from=$columns key=key item=value}
                <th>{if $value.COLUMN_KEY == 'PRI'}<u>{/if}{$value.COLUMN_NAME}{if $value.COLUMN_KEY == 'PRI'}</u>{/if}</th>
                {/foreach}
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
            {foreach from=$result key=key item=value}
                <tr>
                    {foreach from=$value item=v}
                    <td>{$v}</td>
                    {/foreach}
                    <td>EDIT --- DELETE  / EDIT HERE{$value.Record_ID}</td>
                </tr>
            {/foreach}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Sorry for Not Explaining it better. I am trying to get where I have the EDIT --- DELETE a link with the value of the Column that is the Key on the MySQL Table. It's not Always 'Record_ID'

Comment: Is there something blocking you from identifying the primary key in PHP and not in the Smarty template? For the first loop (header) this is fine, but would be cleaner if you just had one further element per line with the value of Record_ID.